# Flexbox spanning a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am new to flex box. I thought of creating a structure like this

[image]

I tried to create this but the last `<div>` d is always coming in a different row

http://codepen.io/srajagop/pen/wzyNVL

```
    body {
  margin: 0;
}

.foo {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;

  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;

  height: 400px;
}

.a, .d {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}

.b,.c {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;}

.c {
  background: red;}

.d {
  background: grey;
}
```

How to solve this?

Comment: The thing is that you are looking for a two dimension layout when flexbox is a one dimension layout. All the flex-items will be in a row or a column direction, never both. This seems like a common misconcepition people have about flexbox. Whenever you want to have this "two dimensional" layouts using flexbox, you will always need two flex-containers to compensate the missing dimension. Making one flex-item a flex-container as well. I hope I explained myself.

Comment: Whenever you want `flexbox` to do a layout like this then you should use nested flexboxes see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39886094/how-to-set-height-to-avoid-white-space-in-large-screens/39886567#39886567) for an example... If you do not want to use nested containers, then you must at least know the height of the container, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39901847/flexbox-change-order-with-column/39902707#39902707) for an example...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't add a margin top property like the above answer. What you really need is a nested flex container, where you have a row flex container surrounding all items, then a column flex container surrounding a and b. Here is a snippet that generally outlines the idea:

```css
.row,
.col {
  display: flex;
}

.row {
  flex-direction: row;
  height: 400px;
}

.col {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.a,
.b {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.a {
  background-color: green;
}

.b {
  background-color: red;
}

.c,
.d {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
}

.c {
  background-color: blue;
}

.d {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is much better. Thanks.

Comment: @karthick Following on my comment, in this example the container with green and red is in a row direction along with the blue and yellow items. The first flex-item is a flex-container as well, and its child flex-items have a column direction. Always maintaining a one dimensional layout.

Answer (score 2):

Used the `margin-top` property. Seems working.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.foo {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  height: 400px;
}
.a,
.d {
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: green;
  height: 200px;
}
.b,
.c {
  flex: 0 0 25%;
  height: 400px;
  background: blue;
}
.c {
  background: red;
}
.d {
  background: grey;
  margin-top: -200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
  <div class="a"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="c"></div>
  <div class="d"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Daniek. I was under the impression that the last box will align in that gap. Any reason why we need to add margin-top ?

Comment: Because, the 'd' div is afflicted by the previous 'c' div, which height is set to 400px. Remember that the default position of block elelements in CSS is `static`. That's why we have to adjust the position of that 'd' div by setting his margin.